# Floating point operations

Tags: floating-point

Is floating point multiplication a single arithmetic operation, same as addition (or) is multiplication done as a series of addition operations?

For a multiplication operation like 7*3, is the operation done is one step (or) is it done as two addition operations[Step_1. 7+7 and Step_2. 14+7]

Comment: Either is a possibility, along with others.  Why is the distinction important?

Comment: The [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) specification requires implementations to return correctly rounded operations but doesn't specify (AFAIK) the computational complexity of these operations.  Common processors (e.g. x86, ARM, RISC-V, POWER) have implementations that are O(1). [Subnormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number) might take longer, but most of the time you're not using these, or they might be disabled and automatically rounded to zero.

Answer (score -1):

No, a floating point multiplication is not a single arithmetic operation, same as addition.   Multiplication by definition is done as a series of addition operations.  Floating point multiply latency on a "typical modern processor" is 7 cycles ([http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~coldwell/MultiplePrecision/fpvsintmult.htm](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/%7Ecoldwell/MultiplePrecision/fpvsintmult.htm))

Comment: "Multiplication by definition is done as a series of addition operations"?!  If this were Wikipedia, I'd say, "[Citation needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citation_needed)"!

Comment: The [page you linked to](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/~coldwell/MultiplePrecision/fpvsintmult.htm) says that for that same "typical modern processor", a floating-point addition takes 4 cycles.  So are you suggesting that when multiplication is performed by repeated addition, the number of additions performed is always about 1¾?